# Idea about isometric embedding in two dimension

Tags: riemannian-geometry, isometry, submanifold

I was thinking how to embed a Riemannian manifold in the Euclidean space. I had an idea, then I found the Nash embedding theorem but I was expecting something different, this is what I thought:

Because the invariant (in $2$ dimension) is
$$ds^2=(a)dx^2+(b)dy^2$$
where $(a)$ and $(b)$ are space functions, we can describe this flat 2 dimensional space in 3d space:

$$f(x,y)=z, \ \ \text{ where }dz/dx=a^{1/2} \text{ and } dz/dy=b^{1/2},$$

so translating in words and if I am correct:

> A particle who moves experiences an elongation due to the curvature which is $a^{1/2}$ if is moving on $x$ axis.

So I believed that for every $2$ dimensions we needed an extra dimensions which codified the curvature but the Nash embedding theorem says we need:

- $n$ (with $n \le  m(3m+11)/2$ if $M$ is a compact manifold, or
- $n\le  m(m+1)(3m+11)/2$ if $M$ is a non-compact manifold.

instead of something like $n!$. can somebody tell me why my idea was wrong?

It's not a question about Nash's theorem, is about my idea.

Comment: See some interesting discussion [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37708/nash-embedding-theorem-for-2d-manifolds)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "elongation", but here are some comments:

 1. On the graph $z = f(x,y)$, a curve along the $x$-axis can be parameterized by $c(t) = (t,0, f(t,0))$, $0 \le t \le 1$. The length of this curve is
$$
\int_0^1 |c'(t)|\,dt =\int_0^1 |(1,0,f_x(t,0)|\,dt = \sqrt{1 + (f_x)^2}\,dt = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + a(t,0)}\,dt.
$$
Is this what you mean by an elongation of $\sqrt{a}$?

2.  Given two functions $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$, there does not necessarily exist a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f_x = a^{1/2}$ and $f_y = b^{1/2}$.

Comment: Even *if* there is a function $f$ with $f_x=\sqrt{a}$, $f_y=\sqrt{b}$, the metric on the graph of $f$ will have the form $ds^2=(1+a)dx^2+(1+b)dy^2+\sqrt{ab}\ dx\ dy$, which differs from the original.